# WPF MVVM change static resource style dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and here is what I am trying to do. I want to change a button's style, which is a static resource, based on whether a radio button is checked on not. Below is sample code:

```
<RadioButton Name="rbInfoCorrect"
             GroupName="InfoQuestion"
             cal:Message.Attach="ShouldProceed">
      <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Yes" Foreground="White"/>
      </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Name="rbInfoNotCorrect"
             GroupName="InfoQuestion"
             cal:Message.Attach="ShouldStop">
      <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="No" Foreground="White"/>
      </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>


<Button x:Name="btnProceed" cal:Message.Attach="Proceed">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WhiteButton}"/>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
<Button x:Name="btnStop" cal:Message.Attach="Stop">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WhiteButton}"/>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

So when 'Yes' is checked, I want to change the 'Proceed' button style to BlueButton (another static resource) and when 'No' is checked, I want to change the 'Stop' button style to BlueButton. Of course this is part of a bigger problem so I just trying to be specific with the sample example.

The part I am stuck at is how to update the StaticResource from WhiteButton to BlueButton based on the radio button checked status. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can replace the entire style using IMultiValue Converter.

For your requirement I came up with this example

```
public class StyleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
       object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length < 1)
                return Binding.DoNothing;
            bool isCorrect = (bool)values[0];
            bool isNotCorrect = (bool)values[1];
            Style firstStyle = (Style)values[2];
            Style secondStyle = (Style)values[3];
            if (isCorrect)
                return firstStyle;
            if (isNotCorrect)
                return secondStyle;
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="StackWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackWpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Name="window" Height="350" Width="525"  >
    <Window.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WhiteStyle">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BlueStyle">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
            <local:StyleConverter x:Key="styleConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Name="rbInfoCorrect" IsChecked="False"
             GroupName="InfoQuestion" Margin="80,19,382,257">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Yes" Foreground="Black"/>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="rbInfoNotCorrect" IsChecked="False"
             GroupName="InfoQuestion" Margin="80,38,391,257">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="No" Foreground="Black"/>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="80,114,294,161">
            <Button.Style>


                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource styleConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="rbInfoCorrect"
                             Path="IsChecked" />
                            <Binding ElementName="rbInfoNotCorrect"
                             Path="IsChecked" />
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource WhiteStyle}" />
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource BlueStyle}" />
                        </MultiBinding>


            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have used this good article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b25973bb-9e9c-4a99-8234-39a042e0a478/apply-styles-dynamically-to-buttons-in-xaml?forum=wpf earlier to tackle my issue.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to change the whole `Style` to do that. You can just add a simple `DataTrigger` to react directly to the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property. It's far simpler to declare the `Style`s like this instead:

```
<Style x:Key="ProceedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbInfoCorrect}" 
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="StopButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbInfoNotCorrect}" 
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Even if you want more properties to change, you can just declare the default ones as plain `Setter`s and the ones triggered by the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property inside the `DataTrigger`. If you have lots of common properties in the two `Style`s, then you can still declare them all in one and base the other one on that one and just add the different `DataTrigger`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I was looking to replace the entire style as I had more than few properties to set in the triggers. So, I was trying to reuse the existing style resources in some way instead of setting the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can replace the complete Style but you can user a DataTrigger to change some properties of the button:

```
    <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WhiteButton}">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=rbInfoCorrect, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=rbInfoCorrect, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Button.Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was looking for a way to change more than just a background property like gradient and other stuff and so I wanted a way to reuse the existing styles resource instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://Globalizer.codeplex.com.

It switches out the entire style when it switches a language.

You basically look up the style in the resource dictionary, kill it and load a new one.